# Angular reactive forms - good practice

Tags: angular, typescript, coding-style, angular-reactive-forms

I was wondering what is the better practice to use.

So the situation looks like this: 
I have a form and depending on user selection I will need different (some of them may be the same) form fields.

Here is a question, should I at start of a base component (where the form is first created) add all possible fields, and use them if they are needed or should I add fields based on the option chosen by a user? (Btw added fields would be added in new components in ngOnInit())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approaches have less side effects. The simplest approach here is to declare your entire form with all possible attributes as a property using a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) or [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder). When you post back to the server on submit, you can post the entire form since the attributes your users never saw would simply be null or undefined.

You'll still have to dynamically show/hide inputs in the template, but the component code will be simpler.

Comment: But is there any difference, like even slightly? And if only it is about clean code is it really cleaner if there are attributes that are not used?

Comment: Dynamically adding and removing form fields requires an event handler method with some logic... not a big deal, but extra code. Further, now someone trying to figure out your code would have to look in multiple places to get an idea of what all the possible form fields are since you're not declaring them up front. These are all relatively minor stylistic things, so it's a bit petty and bordering on opinion. But that's what you seem to be asking for.